# jQuery datatable width changed wrongly at the time of resizing screen from small screen to large screen

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used [`responsive` feature of datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/immediateShow). For large screen, the view is like this:

[image]

For small screen, the view is like this:

[image]

Those views are completely fine. The **issue arises when the page is loaded at small screen at first**, after that if the screen is being **resized to large screen**, views looks like this:

[image]

The width is not same as first screenshot. How to solve the issue?

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/BaBYvqq)

Comment: Maybe whatever you're using to resize isn't triggering the resize events? I saw no problems at all in the demo. I'm on Google Chrome 77 on Linux Mint 19.1.

Comment: You have to load the page at small screen at first. If you load the page at large screen at first, issue will not be generated.

Comment: That is so odd...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting [`autoWidth: false`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth)

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    responsive: ...
});
```

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/ZEEzQVv)**