# Table body not aligned to table header in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10

I've researched and tried all the possible solutions for this, but none of them work for me.

This is the script for my datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Table = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
    "scrollY": 500px,
    "scrollX": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "ordering": false,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });

    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
```

This is my html... I've used php for it's tbody.. and It's css is only for it's background color etc..

```
<div class="card" style="border-top:3px solid #ffcc00;">    
              <div class="card-body">
                <div id="table" class="table-editable"> 
                     <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-Y" style="overflow:auto;">

                            <table id="dtBasicExample" class="shube table table-bordered table-striped  table-hover table-dark table-condensed" width="100%" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>            
                                    <th colspan="7" style="vertical-align:middle">sample</th>       
                                    <th colspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th colspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th colspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th colspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle" class="">sample</th>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th style="vertical-align:middle">No.</th>          
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle">sample<br>sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle">sample<br>sample</th>

                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle">sample</th>
                                    <th style="vertical-align:middle">sample<br>sample</th>
                                    <th style="vertical-align:middle">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle">sample<br>sample</th>

                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class=""> sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class=""> sample</th>

                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>

                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class=""> sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class=""> sample</th>

                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>
                                    <th  style="vertical-align:middle;" class="">sample</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody  style="vertical-align:middle;text-align : center;font-family:arial;">
                                        <?php echo $tbody;?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

And this is the output..
[image: table output]

As you can see `<tbody>` is not aligned in the table header.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Please check number of header value and row value ?

Comment: Try setting [`autoWidth: false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217296/8053274)

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I've checked it.  Nothing is wrong with my header and row value..

Comment: @User863 still not working..

Comment: @Geloxxxx Please include your HTML and css code

Comment: @User863 see the edit..

Comment: @Geloxxxx working fine [here](https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/NWPXpXB)

Comment: @User863 try to resize your browser....